# What does 'Dell Foundation Services' do?

Tags: windows-7, dell-latitude

Can anyone tell me what this software is used for?  It came preinstalled on a laptop and all I can seem to find about it from Dell are some [driver patch notes](http://www.dell.com/support/home/ie/en/iebsdt1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=FJNN9) that says it is for

> facilitating customer serviceability, messaging and support functions.

which is pretty vague.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Should I Remove It](http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Dell-Foundation-Services-141858-program.aspx);

> Dell Foundation Services is a program developed by Dell. The most used
>   version is 2.1.125.0, with over 98% of all installations currently
>   using this version. It adds a background controller service that is
>   set to automatically run. Delaying the start of this service is
>   possible through the service manager. The main program executable is
>   DCF.Agent.exe. The software installer includes 45 files and is usually
>   about 2.53 MB (2,653,600 bytes).
>   Dell.Tribbles.SelfUpdate.Configuration.dll is the automatic update
>   component of the software designed to download and apply new updates
>   should new versions be released. In comparison to the total number of
>   users, most PCs are running the OS Windows 8 as well as Windows 7
>   (SP1). While about 73% of users of Dell Foundation Services come from
>   the United States, it is also popular in Brazil and Canada.

It is safe to disable the service to regain resources it is using.